# Redirect custom taxonomy terms archive to page

Tags: wordpress, redirect, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I wish redirect my terms template to a page with the save slug (to allow the client to custom the page and use a template model for this page), this is my code

```
function redirect_archive_term() {
   
    $categories = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'chapters') );

    foreach($categories as $category) {
    
        if( is_post_type_archive( $category->slug ) ) { // like chapter-1, chapter-2 ...
            wp_redirect( home_url( '/'.$category->slug ), 301 );
            exit();
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_archive_term' );
```

this is doesn't work because of the condition I think, there a way to target them ?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straight forward. The following is untested.

Function has to fire before the header is deployed, thus the use of the [`wp`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/) hook.

[`is_tax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) can fire on search or archive page, we need to filter that out, thus `! is_search() && ! is_archive()`.

We get the current term from [`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) and we redirect through [`wp_safe_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/).

```
<?php

/**
 * Redirect term page to the corresponding custom slug page.
 * 
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71266569/redirect-custom-taxonomy-terms-archive-to-page
 * 
 * @since   1.0.0
 * 
 * @param   void
 * @return  void
 */
add_action( 'wp', 'wpso_71266569' );  //hook into wp's init action hook

if ( ! function_exists( 'wpso_71266569' ) ) {
    
    function wpso_71266569() {
    
        //Let's make sure we're on a taxonomy "chapters" page:
        //Either taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php or taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php.
        if ( ! is_search() && ! is_archive() && is_tax( 'chapters' ) ) {
    
            $term = get_term( get_queried_object_id() ); //Retrieve the current term slug.
    
            wp_safe_redirect( home_url( trailingslashit( $term->slug ) ) ); //eg: Redirect to https://example.com/term_slug/.
    
        };
    
    };
    
};
```